# Redirect and count down, jquery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is our current code:

```
$('#click').click(function(e){
    var country = $("#country").val();
    $this = $("#conv");
    $this.css({"text-align":"center","font-size":"18px"});
    $this.html("<div style='margin-top: -4px;'>We're sorry but this website is not available in your country <strong>(" + country + ")</strong><br /><br /><a href='http://www.site.com/'>Please click here to visit our partner website!</a></div>")
});
```

Basically, we want the HTML to say:

> Please click here to visit our partner website or you'll be
>   automatically redirected in 5 seconds!

We want the 5 seconds to count down, so it'll go 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 and then redirect to the website.

How can I do a counter and redirect the user? I'm guessing `setTimeout()` along side a count variable and `$count--` with a window location href?

Thank you

Comment: Man I hate those "this is not valid in your country, redirecting to..." grr

Comment: @Ben It's all about the benjamins. Geddit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<span id="counter"></span>
```

JS:

```
var count = 5;
var counter = document.getElementById('counter');

setInterval(function(){
   count--;
   counter.innerHTML = count;

   if (count === 0) {
      window.location = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com';
   }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Small question, when the page first loads, it has about a second lag before it shows the counter digit, is there any way to make this display the count on page load, instead of waiting a split second for it to load? So it looks more dynamic? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want the following after the setting your html:

```
var i = 5;
setInterval(function () {
    $("#some_el").html("You will be redirected in " + i + " seconds");
    if(i == 0) {
        window.location = 'http://www.site.com';
    }
    i--;
}, 1000);
```

That will redirect the visitor in five seconds. (Sorry, misread question before)